# Adding a new field to existing Solr index

Tags: search, solr

I'm working with Solr 4.3.0 and I am trying to add a new field to its index.

I have added the field to xml-data-config.xml:

```xml
<field column="session_garantie" xpath="/produits/stage/sessions/session/@garantie" />
```

And I've added the field to schema.xml:

```xml
<field name="session_garantie" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

But I still don't find my field in the query results. Why? Is there a cache I should clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just rebooted the Solr Core i'm working with. 
Thanks .

Comment: any time you make changes to solorconfig.xml or data-config.xml or schema.xml you have to restart solr for the changes to take affect